# Issue on Validation using regex on validator class of spring

Tags: regex, spring-mvc

My requirement is that i want validation on my form field i m doing so using spring validator class and regex so what i m doing here, i am validating my `DepartmentName`field which is in String contains no numeric value any where. This validation i m performing using regex expression `[0-9]` because if it contains any numeric value then  `matcher.find()` return true if it return true i am throwing error message .So problem i am facing is that when i am providing the string with non numeric value validation is done but if i m providing the pure string then still its throwing same message if i run the application again with providing pure String value then its working, but if again i am  providing wrong entry ,validation is happening but after that  if  m providing the correct entry the same message throw so every time i need to run my application please resolve this issue

here is my validator class

```
package com.ankur.tutorial.validator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.DepartmentBO;

public class DepartmentValidator implements Validator {

    boolean found = false;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

        return DepartmentBO.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
    }

    public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
        DepartmentBO departmentBO = (DepartmentBO) (object);
        System.out.println(departmentBO.getDepartmentName());

        if (departmentBO.getDepartmentName().equals("")) {

            errors.rejectValue("departmentName", "department.Name");
        } else {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(departmentBO.getDepartmentName());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                found = true;

            }
            System.out.println(found);
            if (found) {
                errors.rejectValue("departmentName", "department.string");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

this is my controller

```
package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.DepartmentForm;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.DepartmentBO;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.validator.DepartmentValidator;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("departmentController")
public class DepartmentController {
    private DepartmentServiceImpl departmentServiceImpl;

    private DepartmentValidator departmentValidator;

    public DepartmentServiceImpl getDepartmentServiceImpl() {
        return departmentServiceImpl;
    }

    public void setDepartmentServiceImpl(
            DepartmentServiceImpl departmentServiceImpl) {
        this.departmentServiceImpl = departmentServiceImpl;
    }

    public DepartmentValidator getDepartmentValidator() {
        return departmentValidator;
    }

    public void setDepartmentValidator(DepartmentValidator departmentValidator) {
        this.departmentValidator = departmentValidator;
    }

    /**
     * Set to set the view
     * 
     * @param model
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/departmentForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(Model model) throws Exception {
        DepartmentBO departmentBO = new DepartmentBO();
        model.addAttribute("departmentBO", departmentBO);
        return "departmentForm";
    }

    /**
     * Create the department
     * 
     * @param departmentForm
     * @param bindingResult
     * @param model
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createDepartment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createEmployee(
            @ModelAttribute("departmentBO") DepartmentBO departmentBO,
            BindingResult bindingResult) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        departmentValidator.validate(departmentBO, bindingResult);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            modelAndView.setViewName("departmentForm");
            return modelAndView;
        }

        modelAndView.addObject("departmentBO", departmentBO);

        if (departmentBO.getUpdateStatus() == 'A') {
            boolean flag = departmentServiceImpl.actionDecider(departmentBO);
            if (flag == false)
                modelAndView.setViewName("DBError");
            else
                modelAndView.setViewName("Success");

        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the variable found as a class property. Validators are singleton. Move the variable found inside the validate method.

Comment: one more thing i am just confirming that by default all spring class are singeleton until and unless we didn't change the scope in xml file am i right?

Comment: Yes. Spring beans are singletons by default.